# Firebase auth issue on flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

So, issue is simple at first glance:

createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method on Flutter web does not work on my project.

It just gives this error evey time:

```
xhrio.js:630 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=//here is my key, obviosly not showing

net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

and

```
errors.dart:187 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [firebase_auth/network-request-failed] A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:236)

at firebase_auth_web.FirebaseAuthWeb.new.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (firebase_auth_web.dart:157)

at createUserWithEmailAndPassword.throw (<anonymous>)

at async_patch.dart:60

at _RootZone.runBinary (zone.dart:1617)

at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (future_impl.dart:166)

at handleError (future_impl.dart:716)

at Function._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:737)

at _Future.new.[_completeError] (future_impl.dart:547)

at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:603)

at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40)

at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49)

at async_patch.dart:166
```

PLEASE BE NOTED - flutter doctor is COMPLETELY GREEN, all is connected, et cetera et cetera. Trust me, i'm not a newbie at this one. And all is working perfectly on adroid emulator.

I've tried everything. Adressed it on reddit, created issue in github - nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Checking windows hosts file worked (i edited it for my purposes).